# Escaping string within a Java application that would be used for regex matching in Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, regex

I am trying to escape a string within my Java application that would be used for regex matching in a Ruby script

I tried to use `Pattern.quote(s)` in Java but it appears that only add a prefix of `\Q` and a suffix of `\E`.

For example, this is the string that I want to escaped from my Java application and would be used for my Ruby script.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/eclipse:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

I guess I can always use `String.replace("/","\\/")`, `String.replace("$", "\\$")` and etc but it would be nice if there's an easier way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's always bugged me that they chose that approach over backslash-escaping.  Here's what I use:.

```
public static String quotemeta(String str)
{
  if (str == null)
  {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("String cannot be null");
  }

  int len = str.length();
  if (len == 0)
  {
    return "";
  }

  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(len * 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if ("\\[](){}.*+?$^|#/".indexOf(c) != -1)
    {
      sb.append("\\");
    }
    sb.append(c);
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

I'm reasonably certain this will produce Ruby-safe strings.  I did have portability in mind when I wrote it.  That's why it escapes all bracket characters (opening *and* closing) except angle brackets as well as the hash symbol (`#`) and the forward slash (`/`).

Answer (score 0):

Since Java doesn't have much knowledge of Ruby regexp's, I'd venture this would be much easier and convenient to do in Ruby.

```
string_from_java = 'export PATH=/usr/local/eclipse:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}'
escaped_string = Regexp.escape(string_from_java)
pattern = /someprefix#{escaped_string}somesuffix/
```